# How to do Multitenancy in Quarkus 3.0.0.CR2 / Hibernate ORM 6 with DISCRIMINATOR Strategy?

Tags: quarkus

I would like to use Discriminator strategy in Quarkus.
It was not available in 2.X due to hibernate version. So I used a specific filter and interceptor to implement this strategy.
Now that hibernate has been upgraded I've tried it.

But I didn't find a way to configure the Hibernate CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.
Without CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver property, I have this issue:

```
2023-04-18 17:21:24,566 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HTTP Request to /api/v1/condominiums failed, error id: 23a9a92b-2494-421f-8b9f-884589308e83-1: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.setUpMultitenancy(SessionImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.<init>(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionFactoryImpl.lambda$openSession$1(MutinySessionFactoryImpl.java:112)
```

It seems that the [FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.0/extensions/hibernate-orm/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/runtime/boot/FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java#L192) does not configure the CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver in case we just use @TenantID annotation without other properties.

I've tried a workaround using quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties :

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties."hibernate.multiTenancy" = DISCRIMINATOR
quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties."hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" = com.digicopro.base.multitenancy.TenantIdentifierResolver
```

The new issue is that in this way my TenantIdentifierResolver that use @RequestScope does not have access to the RoutingContext.

```
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@RequestScoped
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TenantIdentifierResolver.class);
    @Inject
    RoutingContext context;

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        final String tenantId = context.get(TenantEntity.TENANT_ID_PROPERTY_NAME);
        LOG.debugv("TenantId = {0}", tenantId);
        return tenantId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

and it produces : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext.get(String)" because "this.context" is null.`
Certainly some glue missing between quarkus CDI and hibernate config.

Any documentation or other way to do it ? Do you think it's a missing feature that should be reported and planned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discriminator-based multitenancy is not implemented yet in Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32760

See also https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/32686#discussioncomment-5660392